# CUDA and web development

Tags: cuda

It seems apparent that each core of the GPU could allow for handling of a request, rather than one main processor (the system's CPU) handling all requests. On the surface, it seems like it is possible, perhaps with Templates in GPU + Redis database in GPU GDDR5?

Is it possible and worthwhile?

Comment: While it could be worded much better, I think this is a fair enough question. The fact that someone doesn't have the knowledge and experience that you do doesn't mean that it isn't a real question.

Comment: There is attempt to build SQL Enginge on GPU (DataFrames is near the same as tables/relationships in SQL): https://docs.blazingdb.com/docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How would the GPU access disks, databases, etc.?

Requests are usually short sharp processing snippets. You'd have to load each request off main memory, into GPU memory, do a computation and fire it back again. There's an overhead when transferring data from main memory to GPU memory. Therefore, it's only worth doing a GPU computation if the calculation is long enough and the problem is ammenable to parallel processing on a GPU.

In essence, GPUs are good at stream processing. Not for lots of small requests.

Comment: I am thinking to use only GPU memory without CPU, memory and motherboard. Hard disk is a question.

Comment: How can you use the GPU without first loading your data from main memory onto GPU memory by issuing instructions to your CPU? The AMD fusion architecture looks interesting. Do you know what stream processing is? That's what GPUs are good at crunching. Trust me, if web servers could be accelerated using GPUs, the Intel/AMD architects would have implemented it years ago. That said, I'm not ruling out certain calculations that one encounters on the web being amenable to GPU processing. The only calculations I've ever run on a GPU run for several minutes/hours. Microsecond requests won't work.

Comment: I take it that GPUs can only be utilized in so many specific usages. Rather than having a web server handling requests, there could be a tool that delegate tasks to the GPU. Like roles and permissions for users on entities. I'm just speculating though. The tool should be working in a way that you only dump the data and the task information to the GPU in batches and get the results like so. Need some calculations though. Say I wanna fetch a list of products from the db but i wanna know which one of the columns the user is allowed to see. Is it worth it? idk. maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is valid. There is also another ceveat regarding GPU's, the instruction set is smaller and data is processed in matrices. I.e. same operation applied to every element in a set. So you will need to be very clever in designing what this replicated operations are.

I take it you are considering a GPU HTTP server.